# How to create a dropdown list with user input in a simple form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to use dropdown list (combo box) with user input in simple form, something like this http://pabloaravena.info/mytablegrid/samples/autocompleter/sample_combobox.html How to create this element, or may be use standard element with extra options?